# how to prevent Chrome headless from loading images

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

I am running a test in headless chrome and part of it I want to prevent the browser from loading the images on the page, the page must be a data url and not a normal page.
I am using headless chrome with the next start command:
 `chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222`

I had created the next test to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve. 
but nothing works...

```js
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
const fs = require('fs');

CDP(async(client) => {
  const {
    Page,
    Network
  } = client;
  try {
    await Page.enable();
    await Network.enable();
    await Network.emulateNetworkConditions({
      offline: true,
      latency: 0,
      downloadThroughput: 0,
      uploadThroughput: 0
    });
    await Page.navigate({
      url: "data:text/html,<h1>The next image should not be loaded</h1><img src='http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'>"
    });
    await Page.loadEventFired();
    const {
      data
    } = await Page.captureScreenshot();
    fs.writeFileSync((+new Date()) + '.png', Buffer.from(data, 'base64'));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}).on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can block images using this flag.
It works on canary and stable.

> chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222
>   **--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false**

Comment: Strange thing - with it option on some websites browser can not get css files

Answer (score 20):

With puppeteer you can use the `args` option for passing the blink-settings argument

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false'
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Puppeteer, you can use the code below:

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', (request) => {
    if (request.resourceType() === 'image') request.abort();
    else request.continue();
});
```

From: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/block-images.js